# Sourcing proc tcl leads to an error Options -guard_band or -target_utilization is not allowed for gas-station Voltage Area. (NDMUI-415)

Tags: tcl, physical-design

While sourcing the tcl script in ICC2_shell

```
`proc vol_area_creation {pd_name blockage_name gb_region} {
    set bbox [get_attribute [get_placement_blockage $blockage_name] bbox]
    set llxn [expr [lindex $bbox {0 0}] + $gb_region]
    set llyn [expr [lindex $bbox {0 1}] + $gb_region]
    set urxn [expr [lindex $bbox {1 0}] - $gb_region]   
    set uryn [expr [lindex $bbox {1 1}] - $gb_region]
    set va_bbox [list [list $llxn $llyn] [list $urxn $uryn]]
    set gb_region   [list [list $gb_region $gb_region]]
    create_voltage_area -power_domains $pd_name -region $va_bbox -guard_band $gb_region
    remove_placement_blockage $blockage_name

}`
```

i am getting an error as :

`Options -guard_band or -target_utilization is not allowed for gas-station Voltage Area. (NDMUI-415) Error: problem in create_voltage_area Use error_info for more info. (CMD-013)`

what it actually means as i am not getting ny description of the error.

i tried with sourcing the script first and
giving the proc name

vol_area_creation PD_RISC_CORE pb_1 5.016

What is gas-station Voltage Area ?

Answer (score 0):

A gas-station voltage_area is one that uses a supply that isn't part of the power domain in order to connect cells that you add to the voltages to a different supply.  They are rare and also buggy in icc2.

I don't know why you are getting that error, but why not just drop the `-guard_band` argument?

```
proc vol_area_creation {pd_name blockage_name gb_region} {
    set bbox [get_attribute [get_placement_blockage $blockage_name] bbox]
    set llxn [expr [lindex $bbox {0 0}] + $gb_region]
    set llyn [expr [lindex $bbox {0 1}] + $gb_region]
    set urxn [expr [lindex $bbox {1 0}] - $gb_region]   
    set uryn [expr [lindex $bbox {1 1}] - $gb_region]
    set va_bbox [list [list $llxn $llyn] [list $urxn $uryn]]
    create_voltage_area -power_domains $pd_name -region $va_bbox 
    remove_placement_blockage $blockage_name
}
```